# Update Whole Table adding value from previous row

Tags: mysql, sql

Table `acc`

[image: This Is Table acc]

If I Edit **"A"** Amount to 100 then Total amount change
whole table need to update...
So What Will be the mysql query for updating whole table by adding (credit) or subtracting (debit) from previous total amount...

Comment: Have you tried any solution yet?

Comment: (1) You would need a trigger for this.  (2) This is a really bad design.

Comment: @GordonLinoff - What about using in-line variable assignment inside regular `UPDATE` .

Comment: @GordonLinoff It might be bad design but its just example table so get query what i want to execute... And Thanks Next time i will try to design better...

Comment: Thank... Trigger works... But I want query instead of trigger...

Answer (score 0):

As commented by @Gordon Linoff, you can archive your goal using [AFTER UPDATE](https://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/triggers/after_update.php/%20%22AFTER%20UPDATE%22%20trigger) trigger and a loop. I wrote up the idea as below for example.

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE TRIGGER acc_after_update
AFTER UPDATE
   ON acc FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN

  DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
  DECLARE type varchar(10);
  DECLARE total_amount DEFAULT 0;
  DECLARE name varchar(10)
  DECLARE amount INT;
  DECLARE cur1 CURSOR FOR SELECT name, type, amount FROM acc;
  DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;

  OPEN cur1;

  REPEAT
    FETCH cur1 INTO name, type, amount;

    IF NOT done THEN
      CASE type
        WHEN 'credit' THEN  = total_amount + amount;
        WHEN 'debit' THEN total_amount = total_amount - amount      
      END CASE
      UPDATE acc
        SET amount = total_amount
      WHERE name = @name --not sure about this syntax
    END IF;
  UNTIL done END REPEAT;

  CLOSE cur1;

END; //

DELIMITER ;
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I have two more column date and mod_date. i want to calculate total amount as per mod_date in ascending order.. so is it possible...

Comment: Of course. You can add your order in this line: `DECLARE cur1 CURSOR FOR SELECT name, type, amount FROM acc ORDER BY mod_date;`

Comment: zzT Thanks... Is it possible instead of trigger a query

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[vSales]
AS
        SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY s.[Name] ) AS 'RowNo', 
               s.* 
               , CASE WHEN Type = 'Credit' THEN Amount ELSE - 1 * Amount END As NewAmount
        FROM dbo.Sales AS s
GO

SELECT a.[RowNo], 
       a.[Name], 
       SUM(b.[NewAmount])  
FROM dbo.vSales AS a INNER JOIN dbo.vSales AS b ON a.[RowNo] >= b.[RowNo] 
GROUP BY a.[RowNo], a.[Name]
```

dbo.Sales is the table that holds all the values